# A question about homotopy pushout

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, model-categories, diagram-chasing

Let \begin{array}{ccc} X & \xrightarrow{} &Y \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ Z & \xrightarrow{} & W\end{array} be a commutative diagram in a proper model catgeory and $P$ be the homotopy pushout of $Z \leftarrow X \rightarrow Y$. Consider a commutative diagram \begin{array}{ccc} P' & \xrightarrow{\sim} &P \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ W' & \xrightarrow{\sim} & W\end{array} Then is there any way to construct objects $X', Y',$ and $Z'$ in the model category such that we have a following commutative diagram

[image]

where $X' \to X, Y' \to Y , Z' \to Z$ and $W' \to W$ are weak equivalences.

Thank you in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to involve $P$ and $P'$ in any way-do you think they're relevant?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you should be able to find even $Y'$ providing the front-right face of your prism. In simplicial sets, Let $Y$ be nonempty and suppose $Y\times_W W'=\emptyset$. Then there exists no map whatsoever $Y'\to W'$ with nonempty domain such that the composite $Y'\to Y$ factors through $Y$, whether by a weak equivalence or not, since any such $Y'$ admits a map to the pullback $Y\times_W W'$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Another small and different doubt. Let $D_1:=XYZW_1$ and $D_2:=XYZW_2$ be two diagrams in the proper model category $\mathcal{C}$. Let $P$ be the homotopy pushout of $Z\leftarrow X \to Y.$ So, we have canonical maps $\beta_i:P→W_i$ for $i=1,2$. If $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are equivalent in the Arrow category of $\mathcal{C}$ then is it possible to construct equivalence between $D_1$ and $D_2$ in the homotopy category of the diagrams? here $ABCD$ means \begin{array}{ccc} A & \xrightarrow{} & B \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ C & \xrightarrow{} & D \end{array}